# List item not acting according to a given command

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-float, html-lists

please forgive me if my question is not presented in the usual manner, this is my first time on this forum.

That being said, I have a question regarding the css float. Everything was going fine, that's the problem.
I was making a drop-down menu and made an #ul li { float:left; }. Now when I added a sub menu which is also a "ul li" the float didn't make a difference for the sub menu list. I was searching for answers but the question is so specific it's really hard to find it. I think that it has something to do with the fact that i gave the list items width and height, but I'm not completely sure. Any help would be appreciated.

So I did get the result i was looking for i was just expecting the li's under the info li to also float left since i entered ( #nav ul li {float left;}. It applied to the first row of li's but not to the sub-menu, why?

The code:
Html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./awesome/css/all.min.css">
    <title>navfinal</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Info</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">What is our goal</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Past</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Present</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Future</a></li>
                            </ul>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
body {
    background:#847E7E;
}

#wrapper {
    width:960px;
    height:900px;
    background:#8A8888;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
}


#nav {
    background:#363535;
    height:50px;
}

#nav ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

}

#nav ul li {
    background:#363535;
    width:170px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
}

#nav ul li a {
    font-size:22px;
    line-height:50px;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#D31496;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
    background:#C41BCA;
    color:black;
}

#nav ul li a:active {
    background:#514E4E;
    color:#9314C2;
}

#nav ul li > ul {
    display:none;
}

#nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}


#nav ul li ul li ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:100%;
}

#nav ul > li {
    position:relative;
}

#nav i {
    float:right;
    font-size:35px;
    color:#218BE4;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    padding:0 20px;
}
```

Comment: I just opened up a CodePen and pasted this in and it looks good! I understand you had mentioned subsequent `ul li` elements not having your intended effect, but it would really help to know what effect you are wanting to achieve so people can attempt to help you out with it.

Comment: I edited the question, I just want to know why the 1 set of list items behave differently from others event though I targeted them all with ul li {...}

Comment: The LI are still technically floating; but since you’ve given them a `width: 170px` and they are in a UL that has the same width (in turn inherited from its parent LI), of course they go below each other, because there is simply not enough space for them to be next to each other.